# Telerik Spell Check

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, telerik, spell-checking

I'm attempting to use Telerik Spell Checking for the first time for a textbox, but I keep getting the "Spell Check handler Server Error:500" "No dictionary loaded. Set the Dictionary Path property from the spell checker settings or copy the dictionaries to....."

How do i accomplish this??

```
 <td align="left">                            
     <telerik:RadTextBox
                            ID="RadTextBoxDescInj" runat="server" Width="200" Height="100" TextMode="MultiLine" >
     </telerik:RadTextBox>
 </td>
 <td>
    <telerik:RadSpell ID="RadSpell1" runat="server" ButtonType="LinkButton" ControlToCheck="RadTextBoxDescInj" DictionaryLanguage="English" SpellCheckProvider="PhoneticProvider" />
 </td>
```

Comment: [Here's](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-enable-spellcheck.html) how to manually enable the RadSpell HTTP handlers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error means that the spellchecker cannot find/load a dictionary file. As Kevin said, the default location for RadSpell dictionaries is ~/App_Data/RadSpell/ in your web site. The dictionaries are .tdf files (e.g. en-US.tdf for English). If the files are not there, you should copy them from a Telerik RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX installation. If the .tdf files are in a different location, you should set the DictionaryPath property of the spell control to that path. If the .tdf files are at the correct location but you still get an error, then you should probably make sure the file permissions are set so that everyone can read the files. Finally, I found the following help article for RadSpell and RadTextBox controls - [Spell Checking RadTextBox](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input_radtextboxspellcheck.html).

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable the RadSpell HttpHandlers and add the dictionaries to your web app's App_Data/RadSpell directory. Check out [this link](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/spell_configuration.html) to read more in their help docs.

Comment: won't work for me. I don't have a setup folder. I didn't download it. I merged it from a different branch on a team server.